# How to clear cache of Maui Blazor Window?

Tags: window, maui-windows

I am using Dotnet 6 MauiBlazor. How can I clear the CSS cache of the MauiBlazor window?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps below:

1. Use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+I to open browser developer tools.
2. Check the `Disable cache` option and then Ctrl + R to clear the CSS cache.

[image]

[Reference link.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/developer-tools?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=windows)

Answer (score 0):

Maui Blazor using WebView I believe is just like a browser control. To reset (prevent in this case) the cache of things like javscript and css, I would add versioning to my file links as any kind of web project. So in this example, I am adding a [querystring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) to the file path with "v" (for version, could be whatever) "12345" update this every time you make changes to the css file. If you want to get real fancy and automated, you can add code to automatically set the value to assembly version, etc. but Im keeping it simple here. This is basically a simple "cache buster" effect.

```
<link href="css/app.css?v=12345" rel="stylesheet" />
```